# pandas dataframe: failed to apply lambda function to create new column based on condition if NaN or NA or \n or \t etc then 'No' else 'Yes'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'myCol': ['NaN','NA','xsysdf dfsf','ertrret ertret','\n','sdfdsfsdfsf','erw3242werw']
})
```

What I want to do is to:

1. create a column `myCol1` based on the condition that if `myCol` contains 'NA' or 'NaN' values or 'is Empty' (may be because of `\n` or `\t` like things), in `myCol1` the value will appear as `No` otherwise `Yes`
2. such that, my new dataframe should look like as below:

New DataFrame:

```
 myCol          myCol1
 NaN            No
 NA             No
 xsysdf dfsf    Yes
 ertrret ertret Yes
 \n             No
 sdfdsfsdfsf    Yes
 erw3242werw    Yes
```

And What I am trying to do is as below:

```
data['myCol1'] = data['myCol'].apply(lambda x: 'No' if(str(x) == 'nan') else 'Yes')

data['myCol1'] = data['myCol'].apply(lambda x: 'No' if np.isnan else 'Yes')

data['myCol1'] = data['myCol'].apply(lambda x: 'No' if(np.all(pd.notnull(x))) else 'Yes')
```

But each one of the above code send me the result as all the rows = 'No'

```
 data.groupby('myCol2').size()
 myCol2
 No    223567
 dtype: int64
```

Comment: The first one compares `'NaN'` to `'nan'`, you have to watch out for upper/lower casing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
import numpy as np
exclusions = ['nan', 'na', '\n', '\t']
data['myCol1'] = data['myCol'].apply(lambda x: any([x.lower() == exclusion for exclusion in exclusions]))
data['myCol1'] = np.where(data['myCol1'], 'No', 'Yes')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is almost fine, except for the fact that the expected string is `'NaN'` and not `'nan'`:

```
# data['myCol1'] = data['myCol'].apply(lambda x: 'No' if(str(x) == 'nan') else 'Yes')
data['myCol1'] = data['myCol'].apply(lambda x: 'No' if(str(x).lower() == 'nan') else 'Yes')
```

This one checks the truthiness of the function `np.isnan` rather than calling the function, so it always returns the `True` case.  Additionally, `np.isnan` can't be used with non-numeric types:

```
# data['myCol1'] = data['myCol'].apply(lambda x: 'No' if np.isnan else 'Yes')
```

Here `x` is the string from a single cell in the DataFrame, so `np.all` will iterate over the characters in the string and check the condition for each one.  Since none of the strings has null characters, this always returns the `True` case:

```
# data['myCol1'] = data['myCol'].apply(lambda x: 'No' if(np.all(pd.notnull(x))) else 'Yes')
```

Comment: wow. that's awesome explanation. I learned something new today. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def process_data(data):
    if str(data).lower() == 'nan' or str(data).lower() == 'na' or str(data).strip() == '':
        return 'No'
    return 'Yes'

data['myCol1'] = data['myCol'].apply(process_data)

print (data)
```

Output:

```
            myCol myCol1
0             NaN     No
1              NA     No
2     xsysdf dfsf    Yes
3  ertrret ertret    Yes
4              \n     No
5     sdfdsfsdfsf    Yes
6     erw3242werw    Yes
```

This will work irrespective if u have `NA` values or `'NA'` values encoded as strings.